# Encountered "Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap"

Tags: cassandra

I was executing "c:\apache-cassandra-3.11.9>cd bin" and received the below error:

WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.
Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'
on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured
functionality on this platform.
Starting with legacy startup options
Starting Cassandra Server
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Could someone help on how to fix this?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which Java version do you have, but I had to downgrade to Oracle JDK 8u241 (x64) and is working again.
Regards